# Find the radius of circle whose centre is point of contact of two circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

$\angle$AOB is a given angle. Two circles of radius $r_1$ and $r_2$ touch $OA$, $OB$ and touch each other. Find the radius of another circle touching the sides of $AOB$ and having its center at the point of contact of the two given circles

I made the figure and thought it was not possible to express it just in terms of $r_1$ and $r_2$. Please tell me if I am right or wrong.
[image]

Comment: Maybe start by drawing a picture.

Comment: You should mention the things that you thought of

Comment: @XZCY can you help now

Comment: @DakshLalNigam is the circle passing or just touching all sides of AOB? Also you can attach the figure that you made.

Comment: I have the impression that you are looking for $r_3=f_1(r_1,r_2)$ while you don't even realise that $r_2=f_2(r_1,\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the given angle.

Comment: Does this figure signify your problem? https://ibb.co/YpNZLVP

Comment: @XZCY: please don't use shortened URLs, they might refer to dangerous websites.

Comment: Sorry for not too detailed image but I hope you understand @XZCY
This was the best I could do with that geogebra website

Comment: I've misunderstand problem statement. I've thought that one circle touches OA and other OB.

Comment: Yes, it’s just in terms of the radii.

Comment: Centers lie on the bisector of the angle. Drop perpendiculars from the centers to a side and use  triangle similarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Figure]

Let $\angle$ OC2A be $\bf{\theta}$

In the figure perpendicular from each center of circle is draw to its tangent,and it's distance will be equal to its radius

Radius of C1 = $r_1$
Radius of C2 = $r_2$
Let radius of $C_1$ = $R$

Now,
\begin{align}
sin(\theta) = \frac{r_1}{OC1} = \frac{R}{OC1 + r_1} = \frac{r_2}{OC1+r_1+r_2}\\ \\
\text{On solving these we get  } \ OC1=\frac{r_1}{sin(\theta)};\ sin(\theta) = \frac{r_2-r_1}{r_2+r_1}\\
\text{Substituting and solving for R we get, }\ \fbox{R = $\frac{2r_1r_2}{r_1+r_2}$}
\end{align}

GeoGebra Figure : [Figure 1.1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jih0hmbmnr1i53c/Problem%201.ggb?dl=0)

Comment: Sorry for late answer my friend forced me to leave math and touch grass .

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: How about this construction; the required radius is equal to the diameter of smaller circle. In the case your picture shows, where the centers of all circles are on bisector o angle AOB, you can use similarities to find $r$ in terms of $r_1$ and $r_2$.

[image]

For the case where all centers are on the bisector, $R=4 r_4$, where $r_4$ is the radius of small circle tangent to one ray of angle and two circles with radius $r_1$ and $r_2$. $r_4$ can be found using Descartes theorem:

$(\frac 1{r_1}+\frac 1{r_2}+\frac 1{r_3}+\frac 1{r_4})^2=2(\frac1{r_1^2}+\frac 1{r_2^2}+\frac 1{r_3^2}+\frac 1{r_4^2})$

Here $r_3=\infty$ which represent the line(ray of angle), so the equation reduces to:

$(\frac 1{r_1}+\frac 1{r_2}+\frac 1{r_4})^2=2(\frac1{r_1^2}+\frac 1{r_2^2}+\frac 1{r_4^2})$

Comment: Respectively is not given in the question, so both circles should touch OA OB and each other.